# Linking error when trying to integrate Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I am trying to integrate FB in my iOS app by using Cocoapods. FB SDK version is 5.13.1

I followed the steps described in here: [FB official doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/)

After following the steps, I get the following error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WA10.jpg)

Not sure if this has happened to anyone in here.

My AppDelegate looks like this:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

I can provide more info if its necessary of course.

Comment: try the package manager. more modern and no third party issues.

Comment: seems like your Xcode does not link FBSDKCoreKit to libstdcxx.